# Google place search API JSONP request returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get json data from google place search.

Its returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Below is my code. Please help me. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=xxxxxxxx',
   dataType: 'JSONP',
   jsonpCallback: 'callback',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: You have to put your google api key instead of xxxxxxxx at the end of url

Comment: @IvanGajic that is done by OP as he don't want to share the key.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Comment: Why does this question have 'angularjs' tag? If you are using angularjs, you probably need $http service to work with jsonp

Comment: Well maybe because JSON is not the same as JSONP?